# Number of triangles formed by $k$ sets of parallel lines

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

there are $n$ lines which are further divided into $k$ sets where each set consists of parallel lines. How many triangles could be formed out of them? The lines are not concurrent.

Comment: Show your efforts, please.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_i$ be one of the $k$ sets of parallel lines, which contains lines that intersect the $x$-axis under angle $\alpha_i$. So, to form a triangle, we have to choose $3$ lines from $3$ distinct sets. Hence, we have
$${k \choose 3}\cdot |S_i|\cdot|S_j|\cdot|S_k|$$
options, where $|S|$ denotes the number of elements of the set $S$.

Comment: Someone shared the information: the link is [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/number-triangles-can-formed-given-set-lines-euclidean-plane/) and they say you are wrong (without giving any explanation).

Comment: @ArcticChar Thanks for sharing the link. An interesting programming problem :) And I think that the clue is the same as mine. Maybe the answerer deleted his/her answer after noticing this...